# html page layout with google charts

Tags: html, css, css-position

Im creating a basic web page and I'm not able to arrange it as is like.

It basically consists of a title block, a google chart, and some text underneath the the chart. 
However I cannot figure out how to get the text to appear below my google chart. 
I'm certain my html coding is far from perfect. 
Can anyone advise ?

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">

    .title { 
    background: #03a9f4;
    text-align: center; 
    font: bold 30px Roboto; 
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: white; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)}

    .chart{
    height: 45%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;}

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"     src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></    script>

    <script type="text/javascript">google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
        
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
    ([%BattStats
    ]);

    var options = 
    {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    titlePosition: 'out',
    legend: {position: 'right'},
    hAxis: { textStyle: {fontName: 'Roboto', fontSize: 12, color: '#ff4c4c4c'}},
    vAxis: { textStyle: {fontName: 'Roboto', fontSize: 12, color: '#4c4c4c'}},
    curveType: 'none',
    chartArea:{left:35,top:50,bottom:50,backgroundColor:'white',width:'360'},
    colors: ['#4db6ac'],
    crosshair: { trigger: 'selection',
    orientation: 'horizontal'},
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>

    <!--full page style--!>
    <body style="width: 90%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block; 
    background-color: #ffffff;">

    <!--chart style--!>
    <div id="chart_div" class="chart">
    In order to show the graphs you need an internet connection.</div>

    </body>
    <h1 class="title">Statistics</h1>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `<head>` tag should not encompass your entire body. Think of it as a preamble where you may link in other documents, perform javascript setup or pre-processing, or other work.

`<body>` is where the content of your page should be defined at. Your text should be within the body tag. To put the text below your chart, your body might look like this:

```
<body>
 <div id="chart_div" class="chart">
    In order to show the graphs you need an internet connection.</div>
<br />
    <h1 class="title">Statistics</h1>
</body>
```

Note how the text is contained within `<body>` and also the `<br/>`. `<br/>` signifies a line break, while simply adding a line break while editing the document does not. This stems from HTML's roots in SML, a markup language used in typesetting. Whitespace is largely ignored (outside of tags). Let me know any other questions you may have!

**Make sure your `</head>` comes before your `<body>`!**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. But I still don't get my text below the chart. I've kind the </head> to right after the google chart bits. Do I add another <div> element for the text below the chart? How so?

Comment: Add a </div> before the <br/>. Divs have a beginning and end just like other tags! Perhaps, as below poster suggested, the div should be empty as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very messy which means it'll very difficult to debug where is the problem! Here is your code **[on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lttzzj4f/)**, there are missing codes in javascript about Google charts, try your testes in JSFiddle page to see results.

**Here is your css:**

```
body{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block; 
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.title { 
    background: #03a9f4;
    text-align: center; 
    font: bold 30px Roboto; 
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: white; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)}

.chart{
    height: 45%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

h1{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

**Here is your body**

```
<body>
    <h1 class="title">Statistics</h1>
    <div id="chart_div" class="chart"></div>
     In order to show the graphs you need an internet connection.
</body>
```

Make the div with id "chart_div" empty to render the Google charts.